# Liquid syntax error: Expected end_of_string but found string. Why didn't this work?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm creating a table that goes into the description of a product page with Shopify Liquid. I wrote the table with hardcoded values successfully. Then I tried to get the values from a metafield that is formatted like a CSV. The plan was to have key-value pairs separated by a colon, which are then separated by commas. I could split the list by commas to get the pairs, each of which would be on its own row in the table. Then I would split the pairs by the colon to get each item into its place in the row. I tried it once and it didn't work.

The following is what I tried:

```
<table>
{% assign rows = "Package Dimension:6.06 x 6.02 x 4.75 inches, Voltage:120 V, Frequency:60 Hz, Wattage:5w" | split: ", " %}

                {% for row in rows %}
                 <tr>
                      {% assign details = row | split ":" %}
                      {% for detail in details %}
                      <td>{{detail}}</td>
                      {% endfor %}
                 </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                   
                </table>
```

Please note that the "assign rows" line is actually pointing to a metafield value, but I've taken the text from that value and put it here so you could see what was actually in it. Themekit identified a syntax error "Expected end_of_string but found string in "{{row | split ":" }}"". I tried erasing the pipe, which was suggested as the answer to another question. But that led to a similar error: "Expected end_of_string but found id in "{{row split: ":" }}""I erased all of that and rewrote it. Now it works. But I can't for the life of me figure out why. The following is the code that I got to work.

```
 <table>
{% assign rows = "Package Dimension:6.06 x 6.02 x 4.75 inches, Voltage:120 V, Frequency:60 Hz, Wattage:5w" | split: ", " %}

                {% for row in rows %}
                <tr>
                  {% assign values = row | split: ":" %}
                  {% for value in values %}
                   <td>{{value}}</td>
                   {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                   
                </table>
```

I've put them side by side and tried to figure it out, but I can't. I want to avoid this problem in the future and learn something in the process, so if anyone can help figure out what the actual difference is here, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a very similar problem and found this question while searching for answers.  I believe the reason your first try didn't work is because you were missing the colon after split

Comment: I ran across this for a different reason and the : is what I was missing, thank you!